# load bitmaps efficiently, what is the roll of inSampleSize?

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

I was reading an article about *how to load bitmaps efficiently* [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). it had suggested using some techniques to load bitmap with a size that is *needed* not the real size. the only thing is that I didn't get what `inSampleSize` variable does(which must be a power of 2). if I choose number 1 for that, does it mean that this would be like if i normally loaded a bitmap with its real size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation for [`inSampleSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize)

> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory. The sample size is the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2.

*if I choose number 1 for that, does it mean that this would be like if i normally loaded a bitmap with its real size?*

Yes, 1 denotes no subsampling.

Answer (score 3):

Rajesh has quoted the explanation from the documentation of what `inSampleSize` does; that explanation can be expanded on with diagrams.

The important part is:

> The sample size is the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the decoded bitmap.

So, if we had this image (where each letter denotes a pixel):

```
AAAABBBB
AAAABBBB
AAAABBBB
AAAABBBB
CCCCDDDD
CCCCDDDD
CCCCDDDD
CCCCDDDD
```

And we set `inSampleSize = 2`, we would get a decoded bitmap that looks like this:

```
AABB
AABB
CCDD
CCDD
```

That is, 2 pixels in the original image (`AA`) correspond to 1 pixel (`A`) in the decoded image.

If we set `inSampleSize = 4`, we would get a decoded bitmap that looks like this:

```
AB
CD
```

That is, 4 pixels in the original image correspond to 1 pixel in the decoded image.

Notice than an `inSampleSize` of 2 effectively halves the vertical and horizontal resolutions, but **uses 1/4 of the pixels** - and therefore only 1/4 of the memory.

Comment: Does it does some antialiasing (eg, averaging the pixels values) or just picks a pixel for each 4?

Comment: I'm not sure how the algorithm works, you'll have to check the source.